# Unable to open local file in browser

Tags: android, html, android-intent, browser

(I have checked with the other similar questions in SO)

I'm trying to create a HTML editor. I have an edit text and want to open the HTML code entered in it in a browser. I'm doing this by copying the edit text content to a .html file and then opening it.

```
String filename = "temp.html";
File file = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), filename);
FileOutputStream outputStream;
    try {
    outputStream = getActivity().openFileOutput(filename,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputStream.write(editText.getText().toString().getBytes());
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(file));
startActivity(intent);
```

I have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in the manifest. But after I click open, the *Complete action using* app options I get are Adobe Reader and UTorrent remote. The browsers aren't being shown. I have Opera and the stock browser in my phone. What is wrong with my code? I have used a custom typeface for

Note:

- I do not want a WebView in my app. I want to open it in browser only.
- "getActivity()" because this code is in a fragment.

**Edit:**

```
File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/temp");
        dir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(dir, "temp.html");
        FileOutputStream outputStream;
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            outputStream.write(et.getText().toString().getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(file));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Changed code to write file to external directory. Problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is wrong with my code?

First, your file is inaccessible by third party apps, as it is a private file on internal storage.

Second, browser apps do not need to support `file://` `Uri` values, or even `content://` `Uri` values (if you wanted to use that to expose a private file to third party apps).

If you want to display local HTML, use a `WebView` widget. Or, iterate over the roster of available Web browser apps until you find one that does support `file://` or `content://` `Uri` schemes, then encourage users to install that browser.

Comment: So my solution is I have to create file that is accessible by a third party bowser?

Comment: @ArjunU: Put it on external storage. Or, [use `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to serve the file from internal storage via a `content://` `Uri`. And, in either case, you still need to find a compatible browser. Note that Chrome is not compatible at the time of this writing, though it would appear that Firefox may be for files on external storage.

Comment: I wrote file to external storage. same problem!

Comment: @ArjunU: You will need to have a browser installed that supports the `file://` scheme. Chrome does not. The AOSP Browser app does not. Firefox might.

Comment: There is a stock HTML viewer in my Xperia phone and Opera supports  file:// scheme (got to know both just now). But neither is being shown  in *Complete action using*

Comment: @ArjunU: Hmmm... you can try using `setDataAndType()` to specify that your content is `text/html`.

Answer (score 0):

Android's built-in browser app CAN access files in your private-data area of the internal storage, but it takes some work to accomplish it (I just spent two solid weeks figuring this out).  First, let's deal with the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.  Near the top of the file (just before the `<application>` block) you need to specify this "permission":

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

The `<application>` block will contain various `<activity>` blocks.  One will be your main HTML editor installer-code. Another might be the actual HTML editor.  Another must be the browser-launcher.  That one needs to look much like this:

```
<activity
  android:name="com.android.browser"
  android:parentActivityName="com.myHTMLeditor.Installer"
  android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
  android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"
  android:launchMode="standard"
  android:documentLaunchMode="intoExisting"
  android:excludeFromRecents="true"
  android:exported="false"
  android:noHistory="true"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  android:stateNotNeeded="true"
  >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
    <data
      android.scheme="file"
      android.host="com.myHTMLeditor"
      android.path="/data/data/com.myHTMLeditor/files/MainPage.html"
    />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

That `android.path` data is something you may have to verify with the debugger. More on it below.

Now for the `Installer.java` file --only named that here in this example because of the "Installer" specified in the `android.parentActivityName` above.  That `.java` file needs certain imports for getting an activity to work with files:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import java.lang.String;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
```

The first part of the activity-class for the Installer needs something like this:

```
public class Installer extends Activity
{ boolean btmp, passfail=false;   //declare various variables global to the class
  File apphome, fmd;
  InputStream inp;
  FileOutputStream fout;
  Intent Browse;
  Uri u;
  Uri.Builder b;
  String fn;
  int lng;
  byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
```

The class-function or method that actually does the Install needs some code like this:

```
public void doInstall()
{ apphome=getFilesDir(); //VERIFY WITH DEBUGGER (for Manifest file): /data/data/com.myHTMLeditor/files
  apphome.setReadable(true, false);  //THIS IS KEY to letting the browser access files
  apphome.setWritable(true, false);  // in your application's private directory
```

If the Install process creates a file in that directory, you need something like this:

```
  fn=apphome.getPath()+"/MainPage.html"; //create file name
  fmd=new File(fn);                      //create file object
  btmp=fmd.createNewFile();              //create actual file
  if(btmp)
  { fout=new FileOutputStream(fmd);
    while( /*you have data to put into the file, fetch some of it into the byte-buffer */ )
      fout.write(buffer, 0, lng);  //lng is number of bytes put into the buffer
    fout.close();
  }
  if(btmp) //if successfully created the file, need to make it readable by the browser, too!
  { fmd.setReadable(true, false);
    fmd.setWritable(true, true);
  }

  passfail=true; //only do this when satisfied that all files are installed properly!
```

And now for the function/method that launches the browser to load the `MainPage.html` file:

```
public void runBrowser(View vw)
{ if(passfail)
  { Browse = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("file://"+apphome.getPath()+"/MainPage.html"));
    Browse=Browse.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
    Browse=Browse.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    Browse=Browse.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_BROWSER);
    Browse=Browse.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    Browse=Browse.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Browse=Browse.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    Browse=Browse.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
    b=new Uri.Builder();
    b=b.encodedAuthority(apphome.getPath());
    b=b.scheme("file");
    b=b.path("/MainPage.html");
    u=b.build();
    u.getHost(); //this works to set the internal "host" property from the "authority" property
    Browse=Browse.setDataAndNormalize(u);
    startActivity(Browse);
} }
```

A final note: I was using Android API 21 for this work.  I didn't look to see how far back earlier API versions might be able to do this thing.